# Make event handlers I need accessible method

Tags: vuejs2, event-handling

In laravel 5.7 / vue 2.5.17 / vuex^3.1.0 I make event handlers in my container file MainApp.vue 
with events:

```
   mounted() {
       bus.$on('dialog_confirmed', (paramsArray) => {
           alert( "dialog_confirmed paramsArray::"+var_dump(paramsArray) )
           if ( paramsArray.key == this.addToBookmarksKey(paramsArray.hostel_id) ) {
                this.runAddToBookmarks(paramsArray.hostel_id, paramsArray.index);
           }
           if ( paramsArray.key == this.deleteFromBookmarksKey(paramsArray.hostel_id) ) {
               this.runDeleteFromBookmarks(paramsArray.hostel_id, paramsArray.index);
            }
       })

    }, // mounted() {
```

The idea is that runAddToBookmarks must be called from different pages and I need to set common method check which event is triggered.
I tried in resources/js/helpers/commonFuncs.js to add method :

```
export function addToBookmarksKey(hostel_id) {
    return 'hostels_sorted__add_to_bookmarks_'+hostel_id;
}
```

and to use it in my vue file. like:

```
...
        <template v-if="hostelsList.length">

            <template v-for="nextHostel, index in hostelsList" >
                <hostel-list-item
                        :currentLoggedUser="currentLoggedUser"
                        :nextHostel="nextHostel"
                        :index="index"
                        :hostelBookmarks="hostelBookmarks"
                        :delete_from_bookmarks_key="deleteFromBookmarksKey(nextHostel.id)"
                        :add_to_bookmarks_key="addToBookmarksKey(nextHostel.id)"
                ></hostel-list-item>
            </template>
        </template>
...


</template>

<script>
    import {bus} from '../../../app';
    import appMixin from '../../../appMixin';
    import { addToBookmarksKey } from "../../../helpers/commonFuncs";
```

But I got error : `property or method "addToBookmarksKey" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

Why addToBookmarksKey is not accessible in template of my vue file and which is simple way to work it?
I need to use addToBookmarksKey in many vue files , both in template and it javascript block ?

Thanks!

Comment: try without capitalized A (i.e `addToBookmarksKey` not `AddToBookmarksKey`)

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but looks like that was the the reason of the error. I mean even misspelling error fixing I have error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your helper function inside your component instance to use it within the template:

```js
<script>
  import { addToBookmarksKey } from "../../../helpers/commonFuncs";
  export default {
    //...
    methods: {
      addToBookmarksKey,
      //...
    }
  }
```

You also can define it globally by adding the function in a mixin directly in `main.js`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { addToBookmarksKey } from "path/to/the/helpers/commonFuncs";

Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    addToBookmarksKey
  }
})

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

no need to import and define it inside your components this way.